# Extracting Characters or Words Between 2 Symbols

Tags: javascript, substring, extract, symbols

Is there any way to extract text between 2 symbols? I have been told to use:

```
var email = "forename.surname@arco.co.uk";
document.write(email.substring(.,@));
```

Using substring seems to only work with the position of the character and not symbols. I just want to extract the characters between the "." and "@"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var email = "forename.surname@arco.co.uk";
email.replace(/.+\.(.+)@.+/, '$1'); // surname
```

Or you could use substring:

```
email.substring(email.indexOf('.')+1, email.indexOf('@'))
```

Comment: Your two methods aren't exactly equivalent. Consider the input `first.middle.last@someplace`

Comment: @JammyDoger Just FYI, the `indexOf` solution will give you `middle.last` when used on `first.middle.last@email.com`, while the regex solution gives you just `last` (although you probably don't want to use `.replace` here)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use regex:

```
var lastname = email.match(/[.]([^.]+)@/)[1]
```

Explanation:

```
[.]     # match dot literally
(       # open capture group
  [^.]+ # match anything other than a dot
)       # close capture group
@       # match @ character
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy answer :) But I have to use a substring, although your answer worked :)